# C perform `system("do thing here")` on termination

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, exit

I've been trying to go off of example codes and looking up "C exit function" on Google to get this right but I always get errors when I go to compile. 
In my code, I use this to turn my surround sound from channel 1 to 2 when the code starts.

```
{
   system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1");
}
```

Now I'd like for it to send the same command but with `KEY_1` and `gpio write 6 0` when the program is terminated to switch my audio back to the main input.

> ```
> main.c: In function ‘functionA’: main.c:276:5: warning: ‘main’ is normally a non-static function [-Wmain]
>   int main( int argc, char **argv )
>  ^~~~
> main.c:327:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input  }  ^ 
> At top level: main.c:276:5: warning: ‘main’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
>   int main( int argc, char **argv )
>  ^~~~
> makefile:9: recipe for target 'main.o' failed make:
> *** [main.o] Error 1
> ```

This is the error I get when I try to use examples and fill in.

You asked for it, whole code. (not mine just adding what I needed)

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <pigpio.h> 

#include "main.h"
#include "fft.h"
#include "draw.h"
#include "tabletop.h"
#include "serial.h"

unsigned char use_gui = FALSE;
unsigned char use_serial = TRUE;

double clip_mag = 0;        // dynamic magnitude clip
double clip_mag_decay = 0;   // dynamio clip decreases at rate of some function, this indexes the function
char clipped = 0;            // 1 = we clipped a bin this loop

// Mag: 0.170000 Var: 0.220000
// default trigger levels for detecting beats
double MAG_TRIGGER=    .82; //.36 default was .70
double VAR_TRIGGER=    .82; //.36

struct bin fft_bin[FFT_NUM_BINS];

double fft_global_mag_avg;
double fft_global_mag_max;
double fft_global_hist_mag_avg;     // average of all the bin history averages
double fft_global_hist_mag_max;     // max value of global history
double fft_global_hist_std_avg;     // avg of all the std deviations
double fft_global_hist_std_max;     // max of all the std deviations

struct light lights[NUM_LIGHTS];

int i,j,k = 0;


void hsv_to_rgb( int h, int s, int v, int *r, int *g, int *b )
{
    int f;
    long p, q, t;

    if( s == 0 )
    {
        *r = *g = *b = v;
        return;
    }

    f = ((h%60)*255)/60;
    h /= 60;

    p = (v * (256 - s))/256;
    q = (v * ( 256 - (s * f)/256 ))/256;
    t = (v * ( 256 - (s * ( 256 - f ))/256))/256;

    switch( h ) {
        case 0:
            *r = v;
            *g = t;
            *b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            *r = q;
            *g = v;
            *b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            *r = p;
            *g = v;
            *b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            *r = p;
            *g = q;
            *b = v;
            break;
        case 4:
            *r = t;
            *g = p;
            *b = v;
            break;
        default:
            *r = v;
            *g = p;
            *b = q;
            break;
    }
}

void init_lights(void)
{
    for (i=0; i<NUM_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        lights[i].state = 0;
        lights[i].decay = 0;
        lights[i].last_bin = -1;
    }
}

void detect_beats(void)
{
    for (i = 0; i < FFT_NUM_BINS; i++)
    {
        // shift trigger history down
        for (k=1; k < HIST_SIZE; k++)
        {
            fft_bin[i].trigger_hist[k-1] = fft_bin[i].trigger_hist[k];
        }

        // see if we detect a beat
        if (fft_bin[i].mag/fft_global_mag_max > MAG_TRIGGER && fft_bin[i].hist_std/fft_global_hist_std_max > VAR_TRIGGER)
            fft_bin[i].triggered = 1;
        else
            fft_bin[i].triggered = 0;

        // if this bin is decreasing from last time it is no longer a beat
        //if (fft_bin_diff[i] <= 0)
        //    fft_bin_triggered[i] = 0;

        // add current trigger state to hist buffer
        fft_bin[i].trigger_hist[HIST_SIZE-1] = fft_bin[i].triggered;
    }
}


void assign_lights(void)
{
    int pulse_count = 0;
    int center_of_pulse = 0;

    // finds how many groups of pulses there are
    // marks the center of them
    for (i=1; i<FFT_NUM_BINS; i++)
    {
        // not a pulse until proved otherwise        
        fft_bin[i].is_pulse = 0;

        // if this one is triggered and the previous one isn't we found start of group
        if (fft_bin[i].triggered && !fft_bin[i-1].triggered)
        {
            pulse_count++;
            center_of_pulse = i;

        }
        // if it is not triggered but the last one is we found end of group
        else if (!fft_bin[i].triggered && fft_bin[i-1].triggered)
        {
            center_of_pulse = (i-center_of_pulse) / 2  + center_of_pulse;
            fft_bin[center_of_pulse].is_pulse = 1;
        }

        // skip grouping logic, just count every one
        //fft_bin_pulse[i] = fft_bin_triggered[i];
    }

    //printf("pulse_count: %d\n", pulse_count);


    // go through groups of pulses and map them to lights
    // a light can only trigger if either:
    //     1. we find a pulse that is same place as last time for this light
    //     2. the light decay is zero, meaning it has not
    //        had a pulse in a while so we should pulse it asap

    // assume were not going to find any pulses
    for (i=0; i<NUM_LIGHTS; i++) { lights[i].found_pulse = 0; }

    // first find pulses that aleady have a light assigned
    for (i=0; i<NUM_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<FFT_NUM_BINS; j++)
        {
            // check if we found a pulse that is in the same spot
            if (fft_bin[j].is_pulse && lights[i].last_bin ==  j)
            {
                // we found a pulse for this light
                lights[i].found_pulse = 1;

                // reset the decay
                pulses[i].decay = LIGHT_DECAY;
                lights[i].decay = LIGHT_DECAY;

                // turn light on
                lights[i].state = 1;

                // clear this pulse since we just handled it
                fft_bin[j].is_pulse = 0;

                // stop looking for pulses, go to next light
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    // take left over pulses and assign them to empty lights
    for (i=0; i<NUM_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        // loop through all the pulses
        for (j=0; j<FFT_NUM_BINS; j++)
        {
            // check if we found an empty light 
            if (fft_bin[j].is_pulse && lights[i].decay == 0) 
            {
                // we found a pulse for this light
                lights[i].found_pulse = 1;

                // calculate new position and color
                pulses[i].x = (int)(((float)rand() * (float)(TABLETOP_WIDTH-2) / (RAND_MAX - 1.0)) + 1.0)+1;
                pulses[i].y = (int)(((float)rand() * (float)(TABLETOP_HEIGHT-2) / (RAND_MAX - 1.0)) + 1.0)+1;
                int color = (int)(((float)rand() * 360.0 / (RAND_MAX - 1.0)) + 1.0);
                hsv_to_rgb(color, 255, 255, &pulses[i].r, &pulses[i].g, &pulses[i].b);

                // reset the decay
                pulses[i].decay = LIGHT_DECAY;
                lights[i].decay = LIGHT_DECAY;

                // turn light on
                lights[i].state = 1;

                // save which bin this was
                lights[i].last_bin = j;

                // clear this pulse since we just handled it
                fft_bin[j].is_pulse = 0;

                // stop looking for pulses, go to next light
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // find all the lights that did not get assigned a pulse
    for (i=0; i<NUM_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        // we this light has a pulse go to next one
        if (lights[i].found_pulse) continue;

        // turn the light off
        lights[i].state = 0;

        // decrement the decay for this light
        if (lights[i].decay == 0)
            // once the decay dies this light no long belongs to a bin
            lights[i].last_bin = -1;
        else
            lights[i].decay -= 1;

        // decrement the decay for this pulse
        pulses[i].decay -= 1;
        if (pulses[i].decay < 0) pulses[i].decay = 0;

        // when there is a heavy bass line we want to turn on as many lights as possible
        // also when there is a heavy bass line we will probably be clipping it.
        // we didn't find a pulse for this light
        // we clipped a bin
        // this light is almost free to trigger
        if (clipped && lights[i].decay < LIGHT_DECAY / 2)
            lights[i].state = 1;
    }
}



int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  {
    system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1");
  }
   {
     atexit( system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_1 && gpio write 6 0") );
   }
{
    if ( use_gui )
    {
        printf("init_sdl()\n");
        if ( init_sdl() ) return 1;

        printf("init_gl()\n");
        init_gl();
    }

    printf("init_fft()\n");
    if ( init_fft() ) return 1;

    if ( use_serial )
    {
        printf("init_serial()\n");
        if ( init_serial() ) use_serial = FALSE;
    }

    init_lights();
    init_tabletop();

    while ( !done )
    {
        get_samples_do_fft();

        detect_beats();

        assign_lights();

        assign_cells();

        if ( use_gui )
        {
            if (handle_sdl_events()) return 1;
            draw_all();
        }

        if ( use_serial ) send_serial();

        usleep(5000);
    }
    return 0;

   }
}
```

`

Comment: You've tried atexit()?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if I didn't do the layout correctly, or if it just wasn't what I needed but I keep getting errors when I try to compile with any additions I make when I try to copy/paste examples and replace with what I need.

Comment: Until you show us real code and real errors, we're not psychics.

Comment: ok brace yourselves. I'm not Stack Overflow layout wizard either lol things may get a bit messy...

Comment: The correct way to get a function executed when the program is exiting, is, early in `main()`  call the `atexit()` function.  (See the MAN page for `atexit()`

Comment: I'm trying to use 
`void functionA () {
 printf("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1\n");`
Then at the end I have `atexit(functionA );`

Comment: Post *all* of your code.  What you have posted is nowhere near enough for anyone to give you an actual answer instead of a guess.

Answer (score 5):

This code is almost certainly a syntax error:

```
{
  atexit( system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_1 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 0") );
}
```

I'm not certain what part(s) of the C standard it violates, but it's not valid C code.

The [prototype for `atexit()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.2) is

```
int atexit(void (*func)(void));
```

With this as part of its description:

> The `atexit` function registers the function pointed to by `func`, to
>   be called without arguments at normal program termination.

That means something like this:

```
void myExitFunc( void )
{
    system( "irsend ..." )
}

...

    atexit( myExitFunc );

...
```

The function registered with `atexit()` takes no arguments, and it does not return a value - that's what `void (*func)(void)` mean: "a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns no value".

You certainly can't specify arguments at the time you call `atexit()` to be supplied to such a function when it's called upon program termination.

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there. I'm making some changes to try now, I think I had the right idea just didn't know how to lay it out.

Comment: Now It compiles, but the main code doesn't run. I'm still not getting something right. But I think I'm on the right path now. Might just take me a couple of hours to figure it out.

Comment: @JeremyGilbert One thing to remember is that `system()` *first* executes a command shell specified by the implementation - on Linux/Unix that's usually `sh`.  So complex command pipes may need quoting and/or escaping to work properly.

Comment: The call is a type error, not a syntax error; `atexit` is being called with an `int` when it requires a pointer to function. (It definitely doesn't do what OP expects.)

Comment: There are two problems with the `atexit(system(…))` call.  First, the `system()` function is invoked before `atexit()` is called, so what was just set by the previous call to `system()` is immediately unset.  Second, the return value from `system()` is `int` which is not remotely compatible with the `void (*function)(void)` function pointer argument that `atexit()` expects.

Comment: Agree that it is an error, but I would qualify it as a semantic error (or type error), not a syntax error.

Comment: Well I gave up on getting `system()` and `atexit` to work together and just set an alias to do the switching back when I type `audio1`

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
{ system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1"); }
```

It would be much better to place such a statement in a separate function `yourexitfun`, then the first statement in main() should be:

```
atexit( yourexitfun );
```

====================

regarding:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
     {
          system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output  && gpio write 6 1");
     }
     {
         atexit( system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_1 && gpio write 6 0") );
     }
```

is, as you have seen, not correct.  Suggest:

```
// prototypes
void myexitFunction( void );

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
     atexit( myexitFunction );

     system(...);

     //.... rest of your code;
     return 0;
}

void myexitFunction( void )
{
    system( system( "irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1" );
}
```

Comment: So now I'm trying 
 
`{
     atexit( system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1") );
   }`

and I get this error

`main.c:280:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atexit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      atexit( system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1") );
              ^~~~~~
In file included from main.c:4:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:480:12: note: expected ‘void (*)(void)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int atexit (void (*__func) (void)) __THROW __nonnull ((1));`

Comment: This is the syntax for `atexit()`  : int atexit(void (*function)(void));  That is why I stated to have a function in your program that is called by the `atexit()`  function.   A call to `system()` is NOT a function within your program.

Comment: Well I don't know what else to do. I need it to send a system command at startup, and another at exit.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use SIGTERM and run you command inside handler function

```
    #include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void term(int signum)
{
system("irsend SEND_ONCE newremote KEY_2 && gpio mode 6 output && gpio write 6 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_handler = term;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system()` is not async-signal-safe and can't safely be used in a signal handler.

Comment: I don't quite understand, the line I added works fine turning it on, I just need it to do a different command on exit.

Comment: This is not a good technique to try when the `atexit()` technique works fine.

Comment: A normal `exit` or return from `main` don't use `SIGTERM`